# Kia rio 2012 engi. 1.4 power supply relay

Tags: engine, power, relay, electronic-control-module

Dears,
I have checked a car kia rio 2012 using active test for engine in diagnostic tool all test are succeed except the  power supply relay i tried to locate it but I failed. Could you help me to locate it or explain what shall i do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!